# Proving separability of the countable product of separable spaces using density.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, product-space, separable-spaces

Let $\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{+\infty}$ be a sequence of separable spaces.

The goal is to prove that the infinite cartesian product of separable spaces is indeed separable by showing that the product has a countable dense subset, **arising from the fact that each $X_m$ has a countably dense subset.**

Comment: It's not enough to show "that the product has a dense subset," you have to show that the product has a **countable** dense subset.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $D_n$ be a countable dense subset of $X_n$, and fix a point $x_n\in D_n$. For $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$E_m=\left\{y\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}D_n:y_n=x_n\text{ for all }n\ge m\right\}\;,$$

and let $$E=\bigcup_{m\in\Bbb Z^+}E_m\;.$$

Then each $$E_m=\prod_{1\le n<m}D_n\times\prod_{n\ge m}\{x_n\}$$ is clearly countable, so $E$ is countable. Every non-empty open set in $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}X_n$ contains a basic open set of the form

$$B=\prod_{1\le n<m}V_n\times\prod_{n\ge m}X_n\;,$$ where $V_n$ is a non-empty open set in $X_n$ for $1\le n<m$, and clearly $B\cap E_m\ne\varnothing$, so $E$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: How to know that every non-empty open set in $X$ contains a basic open set of the form stated above?

Comment: @Idonknow: That’s the definition of the product topology.

Comment: when defining $E$ shouldn't the index be $m$ not $n$?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath: It should indeed; thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Let for each $j$, $D_j$ countable and dense in $X_j$
$$D:=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\{(x_1,\dots,x_n,a_{n+1},\dots),x_j\in D_j, 1\leqslant j\leqslant n\},$$
where for each $n$, $a_n$ is a fixed element of $D_n$.
Then:

- $D$ is countable as an union of finite cartesian products of countable sets.
- $D$ is dense in $X$. If $x\in X$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, by definition of the product topology, we can find an integer $N$ and for $1\leqslant j\leqslant N$, an open set $O_j$ of $X_j$ with $x_j\in O_j$. Now we use density of $D_j$ in $X_j$.

Comment: @ DavideGiraudo : In this near-clone of BrianMScott's answer, for a fixed $n$ in the union defining $D$, in which set is $x_j$ for each $j > n$?  In your first bullet point you write "finite cartesian product", and the only way that I can reconcile this is by BrianMScott's answer of choosing a basepoint in each $X_j$.

Comment: @QayumKhan I overlooked this point. But this "near-clone" answer was written four hours before the original :)

Answer (score -2):

Using the fact that dense subsets of a set intersects every non-empty open sets, this is quite simple. In product topology, every open set $U$ in $X = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N}X_n$ looks like $U_1 \times U_2 \times...\times U_k \times X_{k+1} \times...$

Let $A_i$ be a countable dense subset of $X_i$. Then $A_i$ will intersect every open sets in $X_i$. Take the subset $A = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N}A_n$ in $A$. This is countable (countable product of countable sets is countable) and $U \cap A = U_1 \cap A_1 \times U_2 \cap A_2 \times...\times U_k \cap A_k \times X_{k+1} \cap A_{k+1} \times... \neq \phi$. Hence $A$ is dense.

Comment: Countably infinite product of countable sets need not be countable. In fact countably infinite product of $\{0,1\}$ is not countable .