# Is product space of lower limit topology separable?

Tags: general-topology

$(\mathbb{R}_l, \tau)$ : lower limit topology.

I wonder whether $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ is separable.
In my opinion, it is true since $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$:

(sketch of proof)
let $W$ be a open set containing $(q_1,q_2) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. Then there are basic (open) sets $U=[a, a+r_a)$ and $V=[b, b+r_b)$ such that $q_1 \in U$, $q_2 \in V$. This means $W$ contains another rational pair, namely $(q_3,q_4)$. $\Box$

Please let me know if there are any errors.

Comment: Are you using that the lower limit topology is itself separable? If you are, you can use the fact that separability is conserved under the product of a countable number of Hausdorff spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your argument in essence proves the correct statement that the product of  two separable spaces is again separable (this even extends to continuum many (!) separable spaces by the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem,  BTW, but that’s overkill here).

Comment: For anyone curious about the overkill, a sketch of the proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526454/uncountable-product-of-separable-spaces-is-separable/526460#526460), along with references.