# $R^\infty$ is a Polish Space

Tags: general-topology

I have proved that $R^\infty$ is a Frechect Space. From here I have to prove it's also a Polish Space. I am stuck here. Any kind of Reference, Comments, and Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $R^\infty$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe it is $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: For separability, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244427/4280). For metrisability see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362319/4280). etc.